# Scene management using unity MLAPI (Multiplayer)

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

I was reading up on the unity MLAPI and read in the documentation that basic scene management is offered. https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/mlapi-basics/scene-management. However as far as I could see this is limited to placing all of the connected clients and their player prefabs in the same scene. For this use case this works pretty good, I was wondering if anyone has experience using MLAPI and managing different scenes for different players. Basically running a multiplayer game where player X could be in a different scene than player Y, whilst still being able to move to another players scene and see the state of the scene that player caused. A bit how games such as Diablo 3 work. I have no idea where to begin with such an implementation, any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could probably do something like 1. Have a common main scene -> here you also store and synchronize current states of the scenes in data containers 2. Use additive scene loading for the individual player scenes 3. Whenever loading such an additional scene pull the current state (which is synched to the main scene data containers) and adjust the loaded scene accordingly to reflect that state

Comment: Or alternatively to 1 and 3 you could also only request the current state from the server once you actually joined that according scene .. that's probably way more efficient ;)